# assigning click event to div but not anchor within it

Tags: jquery, events, click

A jquery question.

I have a div that contains text and an anchor tag.

I want to assign a click event to the div tag and its content EXCLUDING the anchor tag.

So when I click on the div, an alert window pops up. But if I click the anchor (thats within the div), the alert should not occur.

The div would be something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    This is the content of the div.
    <img src="blah.jpg" />
    <a href="somewhere.html">Click here</a>.
    Some more content.
</div>
```

Any ideas? I am using jquery to assign the click event to the div.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the target of the click since the `<a>` has no children, for example:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'A') return;
  //click handler code
});
```

Comment: I thought of writing the same code but what if he want to navigate to another page using the anchor tag

Comment: @Avinash - This wouldn't interfere with that

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Nick's answer, the following is what I ended up using since it accounts for nested tags.

```
function handleClick(e) {
    var $current = $(e.target);

    // return if we don't want to override another click event
    // check current tag
    var tags = ['A', 'BUTTON', 'INPUT'];
    if (tags.indexOf(e.target.tagName) >= 0)
      return;
    // check parent tags
    var ignoreClick = false;
    $.each(tags, function(i, tag) {
      console.log('checking tag', tag);
      if ($current.parents(tag).length) {
        ignoreClick = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (ignoreClick)
      return;

    // do your normal click stuff here
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emragins/1dscLxx9/)